# What is the difference between "in March" and "by March"

Tags: meaning, synonyms, ambiguity

What is the difference between "in March" and "by March". Is there any ?

Answer (score 1):

*In March* means between 1st March and 31st March.

*By March* means *before March*

> I will finish my project in March. = I will not finish it sooner.
>
> I will have finished my project by March. = In March, it will have been completed. It may be completed sooner than March though.

Answer (score 0):

When one says, 'I'll get this work done *in March*', they mean that they will get it done *in* the month of March, i.e. between March 1 and March 31.

When one says 'I'll get this work done *by March*', they imply that they will get the work done *before* March commences.

Hope this helps.